# refresh a part of webpage in php

Tags: php, ajax

i develop a page in that i need to refresh a part of a webpage,not a whole one in php using Ajax. Please help me to do this , thanks in advance

Answer (score 40):

PHP cannot do this, only a client-side language like JavaScript can. That being said, the [jQuery library](http://www.jquery.com) would allow you to do this really easily with its [AJAX functionality](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

**Index.php**

```html
<div id="scores"><!-- score data here --></div>
```

Could be refreshed with the following JavaScript:

```js
$("#scores").load("index.php #scores");
```

That would load the contents of `#score` from index again without refreshing the entire page.

You could even automate it to refresh every 30 seconds using `setInterval()`;

```js
var $scores = $("#scores");
setInterval(function () {
    $scores.load("index.php #scores");
}, 30000);
```

You can read more about `$.load()` at http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments.

Comment: `$("#scores").load("index.php");` will work fine, here "**index.php**" is the php file which you want to reload.

Comment: The problem of this method is that if you use selector, the scripts would not execute.

Comment: Hi sampson, I would like to know if I can use a "class" to run this load function

Comment: @udoyen You certainly could. A method from your class could output a set of script tags and the above contents.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a basic example using [PrototypeJS](http://www.prototypejs.org).

```
new Ajax.Updater('containerId', '/url/to/get/content', {
  parameters: { somename: 'somevalue' }
});
```

- The first argument is the ID of the container to put the result of the Ajax call in.
- The second argument is the URL to send the request to
- The third argument, in its most basic form, is the list of parameters to send to the URL.

For more details about the Prototype Ajax request, check out the [Ajax.Request](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) documentation.

Taking a page from [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153535/refresh-a-part-of-webpage-in-php/1153560#1153560) nice jQuery answer, here's how you'd execute the Ajax request on a timer using Prototype's [PeriodicalExecuter](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter).

```
new PeriodicalExecuter(function(pe) {
    new Ajax.Updater('containerId', '/url/to/get/content', {
      parameters: { somename: 'somevalue' }
    });
}, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good guide to how the XMLHttpRequest object works over at http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html

You just need to use that, with whatever condition you want to trigger your refresh on, and a PHP script that will output just the data you care about.

Answer (score 1):

fastest way is to use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) load function

let's say the contents you want to change are inside a div

then you can simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$().ready(function() {
$("#dynamic").load("http://url/to/the/dynamic/data");
});

</script>
```