# Refresh PHP include()

Tags: php, include, refresh

What is the best way to refresh the content of a var that is included? For example, I have this code:

```
<marquee>
     <?php
          include('note.php');
     ?>
</marquee>
```

This is great, as I can show on the page the contents of `note.php`.  Say I change `note.php` but I don't want users refreshing to see the changes...is there any way to refresh the included file every 3 minutes for example?

Comment: it's pretty simple, visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153535/refresh-a-part-of-webpage-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To refresh only a portion of a page, you'll have to use some kind of Ajax Request : once the page has been sent to the browser, the server has done it's job, and cannot modify is anymore : the request of fetching a new portion of the page as to come from the browser.

You could do some Ajax requesting "by hand", it's not that hard ; but I'd rather suggest that you take a look at some of the great javascript frameworks that exists out there -- that might be helpful in the future, when adding more functionnalities to your application.

For instance :

- With prototype, you can use [`Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater)
- Or, with jQuery, you could use something based on [`$.load`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Comment: +1 I, somehow, didn't know about the Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater.  Very handy.

Comment: Yah thanks, i thought about this - i just couldn't be bothered to include jQuery :D

Comment: If the only "advanced javascript" thing you need is a couple of Ajax Request, jQuery is probably a bit overkill/oversized, indeed ^^

Answer (score 0):

Only by using an ajax like call.. take a look at prototype or jquery for decent JS libraries to help with this..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you just want to put some javascript in to refresh the page every three minutes, you'll need to look into another technology, namely AJAX. As far as I know, PHP can not do this alone.