# Using AJAX and PHP to refresh data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

have a page that displays a "table" of thumbnails to represent data. Right now I have it where the page refreshes every 10 seconds or so to display the latest data. I've noticed that the page refreshes pretty slowly, having a lot of time where the page frame isn't completely loaded. I did some research and determined that AJAX would probably be the best way to display the data so that the page doesn't have to refresh. My question is - How can I use Ajax to properly update the data on the page? Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I am new at working with Ajax.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

}
else
{
$_SESSION['error']="You are logged in.";
header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/> <!--320-->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=display.php">
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Michroma" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="carpooldisplay.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    <style>
    img.logo{
    float:right
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;

}
<!--
.flashgroup{
border:3px solid green;
}
-->
</style>

  </head>

  <body>

<br><br>
 <div id="display"><legend class="DISPLAY"></legend>
  <?php 
include "../../includes/databaseconnections/demo/database_connection.php";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else{
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (Table2.ID) WHERE Table1.status = '0' ORDER BY dateSelected ASC LIMIT 25";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if ($row[leftGym] == "1") { $flash = "flash";} else {$flash ="";}
        if ($row['photoLink'] == NULL)
        {
            $row['photoLink'] = "endofgroup";
        }
        echo "<a href='leftgym.php?sid=${row['ID']}'><div class='container'><center><figure><img id='{$row["ID"]}' src='images/{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='dragStart(event)' width='150' height='150' class='$flash' >" . "<figcaption><center><font size='6'>" .$row['firstName'] ."<br>". $row['lastName'] . "</figcaption></figure></div></center>";


    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
}
 mysqli_close($link);


 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>

 </div>


 </div>

 </div>
    -->
 </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you recommend? it was recommended to me over mysql_

Comment: @DoTheDew, mysqli is not deprecated. Also, using PDO is not always in prior of mysqli. It depends on your project structure.

Comment: @DoTheDew, just for the record....`mysqli` is not deprecated....I think that you are thinking in the legacy `mysql` extension....

Comment: @Hackerman Fair. I removed it

Comment: @RobertDickey, this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1153560/4980017

Comment: I looked at that example, but like other recommendations it lacks alot of meat to it. How are they getting the #scores? that is what I'm not sure of - the link between the Ajax and say PHP or some database pull